# Access point with whitelisted site

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I need to set up access points for our customers. Each customer will get its own access point. On each access point the visitors can connect to the wifi since its open and not password protected.

What i need to do is to configure a Whitelist so that the visitors connected to this wifi can ONLY visit one specified site.

After quite some googeling i was not able to find an access point model that fits my needs of any brand.

Can somebody please point me to a model that supports this feature and allows me to set up a indipendent wifi network coexisting with the customer's network?

Comment: Please elaborate on your setup... Are the access points located all on one building?, and how do they connect to your internal network?

~edit:Grammar

Comment: Our client has its normal router with wireless access. We add an access point that connects to the router via lan cable and creates its own network. There is just this single access point and each smartphone can connect to it freely. All I need is a brand and make that allows me to make an access point with a whitelist containing a single domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I assume you might be better off using a second router...

You would just set the second router to DHCP mode, and connect it's WAN port to a LAN port on the user's router, and then use the router's whitelist to make such settings.

Access Points are pretty dumb. They don't even look at a frame's final destination, they just pass it along the line. (They are somewhere between layers 2 and 3)

You need something with a real firewall that can do some inspection, and then choose what to do with the packets.

Comment: You could also use a universal network appliance to do firewall magic without needing to make a network inside of a network, but because of supply and demand, that would probably be more expensive.

Comment: are you 100% sure it will work if i connect the WAN to the LAN port? is the protocoll the same? thanks!

Comment: As long as the new router is set to use DHCP (Dynamic addressing) There are some other modes that won't work, If the router asks, you are using a Cable modem